# PHP - How to make condition if no image show image no image available Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel

I am newbie in laravel so I really need some help.

I want to make some code if no image available then it will be showing `no image available` image, this is the example image of no image available https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbxHQ.jpg

This is my controller to store the image

```
public function store(CreateBannerRequest $request)
{

    $input = $request->all();
    //get original file name
    $filename = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    $input['photo'] =  $filename;
    $banner = $this->BannerRepository->create($input);
    //upload file
    Input::file('photo')->move($this->path, $filename); 

    Flash::success('Banner saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('banner.index'));
}
```

And this is the table image code

```
<td>
    <img src="{{ asset('img/banner/' . $banner->photo) }} " width="100px" height="100"/>        
</td>
```

And this is the view https://i.stack.imgur.com/p38Ml.jpg

So if no image it will be show No image available

Comment: Are you want to display if there is no image in `$banner->photo`? You can do it by simply using `if` -  `else` condition in your view file.

Comment: @HirenGohel yes of course :D and this is the example image http://imgur.com/a/755Wo. How to make it im really newbie sorry :DDD

Comment: Use `<td> @if($banner->photo)
    <img src="{{ asset('img/banner/' . $banner->photo) }} " width="100px" height="100"/>
@else
    <img src="path_of_no_img_found" width="100px" height="100"/>
</td>`

Comment: @HirenGohel is that means i need to store the image of no image available (http://imgur.com/ppmPcKA)  first?

Comment: If you want to display simple text you can show it and if you want to display image for 'No_image_found' then you have to define path of that image as per my above comment!

Comment: @HirenGohel thanks man :D how to show as a simple text like 'No mage available' ?

Comment: Do like: `<td> @if($banner->photo) <img src="{{ asset('img/banner/' . $banner->photo) }} " width="100px" height="100"/> @else <p>No image available</p> @endif </td>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Blade conditional

Default text if no image available

```
<td>
    @if ($banner->photo)
        <img src="{{ asset('img/banner/' . $banner->photo) }} " width="100px" height="100"/> 
    @else
        No image available
    @endif       
</td>
```

Default image if no image available

```
<td>
    <img src="{{ asset($banner->photo ? 'img/banner/' . $banner->photo : 'default-image.png') }} " width="100px" height="100"/>     
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D but how to show if no image as a image this is the example image http://imgur.com/ppmPcKA

Comment: Thanks for the help :D i try your code but it still didnt show http://imgur.com/a/i5a2t

Comment: updated the answer. replace `'default-image.png'` with your default image path

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can u show me too if no image it will be display text "No image Availble". So i have 2 choice using with text and image :)))

Comment: Thanks for the help i try your second code what is 'default-image.png' means?

Comment: It should be replaced with path of your image which gets displayed when there is no image available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151937/discussion-between-chanafdo-and-sahat-riyanto).

Answer (score 0):

@if ($banner->photo)
        photo) }} " width="100px" height="100"/> 
    @else
       
    @endif

//from the above you can use if-else statement to fix it up.
Hope it will hepls you :)